# How to solve ggplot2 error "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'melanoma.hx' not found"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a grouped histogram using ggplot2 using the following code:

```
mu <- mcompleted %>% group_by(melanoma.hx) %>% summarise(grp.mean = mean(age))
mu

theme_set(theme_classic() + theme(legend.position = "top"))

# Change line color by melanoma hx
ggplot(mcompleted, aes(x = age)) + geom_histogram(aes(color = melanoma.hx), fill = "white", position = "identity", bins = 30) + scale_color_manual(values = c("#56B4E9", "#EFC000FF"))

# change fill and outline color manually 
p<- ggplot(mcompleted, aes(x = age)) + geom_histogram(aes(color = melanoma.hx, fill = melanoma.hx), position = "identity", bins = 50, alpha = 0.4) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = grp.mean, color = melanoma.hx), data = mu, linetype = "dashed") + scale_color_manual(values = c("#56B4E9", "#EFC000FF")) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#56B4E9", "#EFC000FF"))

p+ labs(fill = "Melanoma", color = "Melanoma")
```

I have previously used these lines of code successfully using a different dataset, but this time I am getting the following error message:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'melanoma.hx' not found

This is after I run the last line of code: `p+ labs(fill = "Melanoma", color = "Melanoma")`.

Comment: I would guess your error is also going to be found when you just run `p` too, right?  If that's the case, debug to find where it occurs by plotting layer by layer:  first the `ggplot()` part, then add the `geom_histogram()`... etc etc.  Is there the column `melanoma.hx` in the `mu` dataset?  It is likely either not finding the column in there or in `mcompleted`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I found that the column `melanoma.hx` wasn't in the `mu` dataset, so I rewrote the first line of code to: `mu <- ddply(mcompleted, "melanoma.hx", summarise, grp.mean=mean(age))`. This has solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to have helped out.  Layer-by-layer problem solving works very well in `ggplot`, since that's how the plot can be built.  Very useful to figure out stuff like this.  Also important to note that storing `gg` objects to a variable (like `p` in your case) only write a list.  The actual plot code is not executed until you "display" the list.  This is why you see the error that happened in your "assignment" code (`p <- ggplot(...`) only when you ran the last line (`p + labs(...`).